# Bulk collect into specific columns of collection

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
TYPE t_project_financial_table IS TABLE OF project_financial%ROWTYPE;
g_project_financial_table t_project_financial_table;
```

The table project_financial has 15 columns. The select statement returns 2 columns. Can I bulk collect into 2 specific columns of the collection g_project_financial_table and leave the other columns null or do I have to bulk collect into 2 varrays (for each column) and loop over those to get the values of the 2 columns into the collection g_project_financial_table.

Something like BULK COLLECT INTO g_project_financial_table.column3, g_project_financial_table.column8 ?

```
SELECT k.tag, 
  (SELECT pa.available
   FROM pers_account pa
   WHERE pa.valid_from = 
     (SELECT MAX(pa2.valid_from)
      FROM pers_account pa2
      WHERE pa2.valid_from <= k.tag)) AS available

BULK COLLECT INTO g_project_financial_table ??????? 

FROM kalender k
WHERE k.tag BETWEEN to_date('20120430','YYYYMMDD')
                AND to_date('20120504','YYYYMMDD')
  AND k.ist_werktag = 1
ORDER BY k.tag;
```

Comment: Why don't you amend your select to select null values for the remaining 13 columns in `PROJECT_FINANCIAL`? That way you can bulk collect directly into the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that for large date ranges the performance of this query is becoming an issue, because you execute 2 extra queries for each row, right?

Anyway, my solution would be to collect into 2 collections if you want to bulk insert.
But honoustly, this doesn't look like you are going to insert huge numbers of rows, so it might be easiest to just use a normal insert. Here's the bulk insert anyway.

```
create or replace procedure add_days_to_financial(p_date_from in date, p_date_to in date)
as
    cursor cur_kalender
    is
    SELECT k.tag, 
      (SELECT pa.available
       FROM pers_account pa
       WHERE pa.valid_from = 
         (SELECT MAX(pa2.valid_from)
          FROM pers_account pa2
          WHERE pa2.valid_from <= k.tag)) AS available
    FROM kalender k
    WHERE k.tag BETWEEN p_date_from and p_date_to
      AND k.ist_werktag = 1
    ORDER BY k.tag;

    type t_tag is table of kalender.tag%type;
    type t_available is table of kalender.available%type;

    arr_tag t_tag;
    arr_available t_available;
begin
    open cur_kalender;
    loop
        fetch cur_kalender bulk collect into arr_tag, arr_available limit 500;

        forall i in arr_tag.first .. arr_tag.last
            insert into project_financial
            (tag, available)
            values
            (arr_tag(i), arr_available(i));

        commit;
        exit when cur_kalender%notfound;
    end loop;

    close cur_kalender;

    commit;
exception
    when others then 
        -- log? 
        raise;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot collect data into just 2 columns of a 15 column record.  You could, however, add 13 additional NULL columns in the appropriate positions to your `SELECT` statement.  Or, as you suggested, you could bulk collect the data into two different collections.